# Bi directional full relation between classes + small working tasks

Tags: java

I did this the way I could (I mean this way I find it okay for my knowledge and of course the most important **output is the correct one** , but as I know it is also important that the code looks clean and minimal).

I have to figure out some tasks that you will see in the output, apart one where I have to implement bi directional full relation between these two objects. (Mother may have many children; a child has exactly one mother). (Apparently the one thing that give me headache since I took 2 days to figure out how to implement the relation between).

I want to see if I can improve the code

- Can it be minimized?
- Is the approach correct?
- Is it the fastest way?

I will appreciate any of your suggestions.

### Class Person:

```
  package victor;

public abstract class Person {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Person(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

### Class Mother:

```
package victor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Mother extends Person {
    private int age;
    private final List<Newborn> list;

    public Mother(String name, int id, int age) {
        super(name, id);
        this.age = age;
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Newborn> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId() + " " + getName() + " " + age;
    }
}
```

### Class Newborn:

```
package victor;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Newborn extends Person {
    private boolean gender;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private int weight;
    private int height;
    private int motherID;
    private Mother mother;

    public Newborn(String name, int id, boolean gender
            , String birthday, int weight, int height
            , int motherID) {
        super(name, id);
        this.gender = gender;
        parseBirthday(birthday);
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.motherID = motherID;
    }

    public boolean getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(boolean gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public Mother getMother() {
        return mother;
    }

    public int getMotherID() {
        return motherID;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public void setMother(Mother mother) {
        this.mother = mother;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setMotherID(int motherID) {
        this.motherID = motherID;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void parseBirthday(String format) {
        DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
        this.birthday = LocalDate.parse(format, sdf);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId() + " " + (gender ? "s " : "c ")
                + getName() + " " + birthday.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
                + " " + weight + " " + height + " " + motherID;
    }
}
```

### Class App + Main(code):

```
package victor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class App {
    private List<Mother> mothers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Newborn> newborns = new ArrayList<>();

    public void importMothers(String filename) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
                mothers.add(new Mother(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[0])
                        , Integer.parseInt(arr[2])));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void importNewborns(String filename) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
                newborns.add(new Newborn(arr[2], Integer.parseInt(arr[0])
                        , arr[1].equals("c") ? false : true
                        , arr[3], Integer.parseInt(arr[4])
                        , Integer.parseInt(arr[5])
                        , Integer.parseInt(arr[6])));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void buildRelation(String momsFilename, String newbornsFilename) {
        importMothers(momsFilename);
        importNewborns(newbornsFilename);
        for (Newborn newborn : newborns) {
            findMother(newborn);
        }
    }

    public void findMother(Newborn newborn) {
        for (Mother mother : mothers) {
            if (newborn.getMotherID() == mother.getId()) {
                mother.getList()
                        .add(newborn);
                newborn.setMother(mother);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public Newborn getTallestNewborn(boolean son) {
        Newborn tallest = null;
        int height = 0;

        for (Newborn newborn : newborns) {
            if (newborn.getHeight() > height && newborn.getGender() == son) {
                tallest = newborn;
                height = newborn.getHeight();
            }
        }

        return tallest;
    }

    public LocalDate mostCommonDate() {
        Map<LocalDate, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (Newborn newborn : newborns) {
            Integer value = map.get(newborn.getBirthday());
            map.put(newborn.getBirthday(), (value == null) ? 1 : value + 1);
        }

        Entry<LocalDate, Integer> max = null;

        for (Entry<LocalDate, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (max == null || max.getValue() > entry.getValue()) {
                max = entry;
            }
        }

        assert max != null;
        return max.getKey();
    }

    public List<Mother> motherMoreThan() {
        List<Mother> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Mother mother : mothers) {
            if (mother.getAge() > 25 && isChildOver4000(mother)) {
                list.add(mother);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public boolean isChildOver4000(Mother mother) {
        for (Newborn newborn : mother.getList()) {
            if (newborn.getWeight() > 4000) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public List<Newborn> newbornWithMotherName() {
        List<Newborn> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Newborn newborn : newborns) {
            if (!newborn.getGender())
                if (newborn.getMother()
                        .getName()
                        .equals(newborn.getName()))
                    list.add(newborn);

        }

        return list;
    }

    public List<Mother> mothersWithTwins() {
        List<Mother> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Mother mother : mothers) {
            if (motherHasTwins(mother)) {
                list.add(mother);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public boolean motherHasTwins(Mother mother) {
        Set<LocalDate> set = new TreeSet<>();

        for (Newborn newborn : mother.getList()) {
            set.add(newborn.getBirthday());
        }

        return set.size() < mother.getList()
                .size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.buildRelation("src\\motherFile.txt", "src\\\\NewbornFile.txt");

        System.out.println("Tallest daughter:");
        System.out.println(app.getTallestNewborn(false));
        System.out.println("\nTallest son:");
        System.out.println(app.getTallestNewborn(true));
        System.out.println("\nMost common date:");
        System.out.println(app.mostCommonDate());
        System.out.println("\nMothers over 25 Years old with childer heavier than 4000g;");
        app.motherMoreThan()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("\nDaughters that inherits their mother's name: ");
        app.newbornWithMotherName()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("\nMother that has twins:");
        app.mothersWithTwins()
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us perhaps 10-50 representative lines from `motherFile.txt` and `NewbornFile.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the fastest way?

Probably not, though there's a lot to work on before performance considerations necessarily factor in.

> Can it be minimized?

Yes!

> Is the approach correct?

Effectively impossible to say unless you give more information as to why you're doing the things you're doing. If this is for a real-life, production database of hospital patients, a flat text file is not a good idea (for instance).

Many more of your fields should be `final` than you currently have; immutability bestows a number of benefits. As other reviewers have mentioned, circular dependencies complicate this, and if they're avoided then your classes can be made fully immutable. Don't blindly add getters and setters for their own sake.

Consider using a `String.format` call in your `toString` implementations.

`gender` being a boolean is effectively wrong. First of all, you've given it a name that leaves the programmer guessing as to which boolean value evaluates to which gender (seems like male is `true` based on inference); so a better variable name would be `male` or `isMale`. Just as important, though: [intersex babies are real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex) and any effort to cast them to a boolean doesn't at all fit reality. Depending on how medically detailed you need your database to be, either an enum or a simple string value will fit better. Adding to this: what on earth are "c" and "s"?

`parseBirthday` should be made a `static` returning a `LocalDate`, and should not set the `birthday` member.

Your `import` functions should either be static pseudoconstructor methods on their respective models, or perhaps dedicated parser classes; but should not exist in `App`.

`buildRelation` prevents the `App` instance from being immutable, so move its contents to a constructor.

`findMother` is inefficient. Rather than looping, you should use a hash map lookup.

Basically all of your analysis methods could be improved by use of streams.

`motherHasTwins` is inefficient since it unconditionally iterates the entire collection of newborns. Instead, as soon as you find a duplicate you should break the loop.

Including the word "file" in your filename is redundant.

Don't hard-code `\n` as that's a system-specific newline; prefer `%n` in `printf`-like calls or use `println`.

Some of your fields - height, weight and age - are mysteries. Weight appears to be in grams and age in years, but you don't mention this anywhere. One way to have the code self-document this is to bake the unit into the variable name, as in `weightGrams`. Also, all three of these quantities are continuous in real life, so should be represented as floats and not ints.

Consider using a streamed implementation for producing parsed records from your files.

### Suggested

Covering some of the above:

**App.java**

```java
package victor;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class App {
    private final Map<Integer, Mother> mothers;
    private final List<Newborn> newborns;

    public App(Path momsPath, Path newbornsPath) throws IOException {
        newborns = Newborn.importFromFile(newbornsPath)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map<Integer, List<Newborn>> newbornsByMother = Newborn.newbornsByMother(newborns);

        mothers = Mother.importFromFile(momsPath, newbornsByMother)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                m -> m.id, Function.identity()
            ));
    }

    public Newborn getTallestNewborn(boolean male) {
        return newborns.stream()
            .filter(n -> n.male == male)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(n -> n.height))
            .get();
    }

    public LocalDate mostCommonBirthday() {
        return newborns.stream()
            .map(n -> n.birthday)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .get()
            .getKey();
    }

    public Stream<Mother> motherMoreThan() {
        return mothers.values().stream()
            .filter(
                m -> m.age > 25 && m.anyChildHeavierThan(4000)
            );
    }

    public Stream<Newborn> daughtersWithMothersName() {
        return newborns.stream()
            .filter(
                n -> !n.male &&
                    n.name.equals(mothers.get(n.motherID).name)
            );
    }

    public Stream<Mother> mothersWithTwins() {
        return mothers.values().stream()
            .filter(Mother::hasTwins);
    }

    public void describe(PrintWriter out) {
        out.printf(
            "Tallest daughter:"
            + "%n%s"
            + "%n"
            + "%nTallest son:"
            + "%n%s"
            + "%n"
            + "%nMost common birthday:"
            + "%n%s"
            + "%n"
            + "%n",
            getTallestNewborn(false),
            getTallestNewborn(true),
            mostCommonBirthday()
        );

        out.println("Mothers over 25 Years old with children heavier than 4 kg:");
        motherMoreThan()
            .forEach(out::println);


        out.printf("%nDaughters that inherits their mother's name:%n");
        daughtersWithMothersName()
            .forEach(out::println);

        out.printf("%nMother that has twins:%n");
        mothersWithTwins()
            .forEach(out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        App app = new App(Path.of("mothers.txt"), Path.of("newborns.txt"));
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out)) {
            app.describe(out);
        }
    }
}
```

**Mother.java**

```java
package victor;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Mother extends Person {
    public final float age;
    private final List<Newborn> children;

    public Mother(String name, int id, float age, List<Newborn> children) {
        super(name, id);
        this.age = age;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public List<Newborn> getChildren() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d %s %.1f", id, name, age);
    }

    public static Mother fromString(String line, Map<Integer, List<Newborn>> newbornsByMother) {
        String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        String name = arr[1];
        float age = Float.parseFloat(arr[2]);

        return new Mother(name, id, age, newbornsByMother.get(id));
    }

    public static Stream<Mother> importFromFile(
        @NotNull Path path, Map<Integer, List<Newborn>> newbornsByMother
    ) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(path)
            .map(line -> fromString(line, newbornsByMother));
    }

    public boolean anyChildHeavierThan(float weight) {
        return children.stream()
            .anyMatch(n -> n.weight > weight);
    }

    public boolean hasTwins() {
        Set<LocalDate> birthdays = new HashSet<>();
        return !children.stream()
            .map(n -> n.birthday)
            .allMatch(birthdays::add);
    }
}
```

**Newborn.java**

```java
package victor;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Newborn extends Person {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter birthdayFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;

    public final boolean male;
    public final LocalDate birthday;
    public final float weight;
    public final float height;
    public final int motherID;

    public Newborn(
        String name, int id, boolean male,
        LocalDate birthday, float weight, float height,
        int motherID
    ) {
        super(name, id);
        this.male = male;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.motherID = motherID;
    }

    private static LocalDate parseBirthday(String date) {
        return LocalDate.parse(date, birthdayFormat);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "%d %c %s %s %.1f %.1f %d",
            id,
            male ? 's' : 'c',
            name,
            birthday.format(birthdayFormat),
            weight, height, motherID
        );
    }

    public static Newborn fromString(String line) {
        String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");

        int id = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        boolean male = !"c".equals(arr[1]);
        String name = arr[2];
        LocalDate birthday = parseBirthday(arr[3]);
        float weight = Float.parseFloat(arr[4]);
        float height = Float.parseFloat(arr[5]);
        int motherID = Integer.parseInt(arr[6]);

        return new Newborn(name, id, male, birthday, weight, height, motherID);
    }

    public static Stream<Newborn> importFromFile(@NotNull Path path) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(path)
            .map(Newborn::fromString);
    }

    public static Map<Integer, List<Newborn>> newbornsByMother(Collection<Newborn> newborns) {
        return newborns.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n.motherID));
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```java
package victor;

public abstract class Person {
    public final String name;
    public final int id;

    public Person(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, 
First of all I want to say thank you because you took your time to fully review the code. 
Indeed as you mention I did not provide full information  on why I did some things and what I needed from the code exactly.  
Short long story : 
I head to implement bi directional relation between mother and child. One to many. The I just head the small tasks to get the correct output for the "tasks" 
They aproov it and they where surprised that it was OK Everithing, as regarding the code they said that is not bad, but we need to take in consideration that I am new 

Comment: So, I understood  why thay said is not bad code! since I am an "junior", I looked at what you advise and indeed using stream looks more good the the eyes . But I didn't  feel confortabile using team and also I could not get the correct output with teams. So I have to learn more about streams . Once again. Thank you for your time and accepting to review  something that you did not have why it was like that and other missing informations 

Answer (score 4):

Your class structure is seriously flawed. How would you describe your relationship to your grandmother?

- you: `Newborn` instance, with `mother` referring to your mother.
- mother: `Mother` instance, with a reference to you in the `list`. But at the same time, it must be a `Newborn`, to be able to catch the relationship to your grandmother.
- grandmother: `Mother` instance, with a reference to your mother in the `list`.

You're not able to express that a person can be a mother and a child at the same time, although this is absolutely natural in the real world.

Throw away the subclasses and allow any `Person` to have both parents and children.

Comment: Hello ,  
I head to implement bi directional full relation between this objects. (Mother may have many children, children has exactly one mother). I am not looking to get  a a relation  to grandmother . That is why I did like this . Please correct me if what i said doesn't make sanse.

Comment: In CodeReview, we are invited to comment on any aspect of your code that comes to our minds, not only the ones you explicitly ask about. That's the nature of code review.

Comment: My reading of Birsan's comment is not that he's attempting to constrain your feedback, but that he's attempting to constrain the surface area and purpose of his program - and that's a good idea. If the program has nothing to do with grandmothers, and is only for (e.g.) a natal ward in a hospital, feature creep is a bad thing and it actually makes sense to _only_ model what you need to model and no more. So on the whole, I disagree with this answer.

Comment: Given the use of the term "newborn", it may be that grandparental relations are a matter of YAGNI here. I'm not saying your review is without merit, but there may be a specific context which solely focuses on newly born babies (and their mother) at which point the grandmother is not a relevant counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

- Can it be minimized?

Shortening code is not something that holds any meaningful production value. Code should be made to be maintainable and achieving that goal may make the code shorter or longer.

- Is the approach correct?

No. `Mother` depends on `Newborn` and `Newborn` depends on `Mother`, creating a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). While the compiler allows it, it is bad design. Hierarchies like this are usually implemented using roles. A person has role of "mother" or "child" or both. It's usually a set of values. `Newborn` as a class is broken by design, as being a newborn is a status that changes constantly during the lifetime of the object and can be calculated from person's date of birth. Also, most mothers have children but all newborns do not have mothers.

- Is it the fastest way?

Trying to optimize a piece of code, of which you don't know whether it is a performance bottle neck or not, is called [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: Whereas a circular dependency indeed may be bad design, that doesn't meet the threshold for being incorrect.